# [plotly]Why there is have unaviable sample in the x axis

Tags: python, plotly

Create a Bar illustration with plotly, assign a list to x axis which value is uncontinuous, but there is still have unavible label in x axis. how to remove them.
Code:

```
from plotly.graph_objs import Bar, Layout
from plotly import offline
from die import Die

die1 = Die(num_sides=6)
die2 = Die(num_sides=6)

results = []
for roll_num in range(100_000):
    result = die1.roll()*die2.roll()
    results.append(result)

frequencies = []

x_sample_list = []
for i in range(1, die1.num_sides+1):
    for j in range(1, die2.num_sides+1):
        x = i*j
        if x in x_sample_list:
            continue
        x_sample_list.append(x)

x_values = x_sample_list[:]
x_values.sort()

for value in x_values:
    frequency = results.count(value)
    frequencies.append(frequency)

data = [Bar(x=x_values, y=frequencies)]

x_axis_config = {'title': 'Sample', 'dtick': 1}
y_axis_config = {'title': 'Frequency'}

my_layout = Layout(title='roll out for 1000 times of a six side Die', xaxis=x_axis_config, yaxis=y_axis_config)

offline.plot({'data': data, 'layout': my_layout}, filename='die.html')

from random import randint

from random import randint
```

The Die class is for genarate a number in random, value between 1~6

```
class Die:

def __init__(self, num_sides=6):
    self.num_sides = num_sides

def roll(self):
    return randint(1, self.num_sides)
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure this is because you cant get some x-axis values by multiplying two numbers between 1 and 6 - try making a list of all pairs of numbers between 1 and 6 multiplied (1x1, 2x1, 3x1, 4x1, 5x1, 6x1, 2x2, 3x2.....) and only including x vals that are in that list

Comment: You see the x vals is coming from data = [Bar(x=x_values, y=frequencies)] , and x_values is copy from the list x_sample_list which  is generate die1*die2,which has exclude the unvialable value, print out x_values below: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, 25, 30, 36]

Comment: Event I assigin the x_values a uncontinues list, e.g. [1, 3, 5, 10], there is still have uncontinues x vals

Comment: hmmm ok maybe its your dtick = 1 in xaxis config?  Looks like that forces a 1-increment on the x-axis ticks, try removing dtick=1 from the xaxis config (https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/)

Comment: also out of interest why do you have x_values rather than just using x_sample_list if its a copy?

Comment: Tried to remove dtick doesn't help,  only just make the x vals more coarse. use x_values rather than x_sample_list concern the x_sample_list's value and length maybe dynamic

Comment: well it looks like the extra vals are being added in the formatting step after data =[bar], the 'x' attribute of bar doesnt have the unwanted vals.  Try removing the x_axis_config altogether, perhaps it's resetting to a default somehow - not going to lie though I'm a bit stumped too :P Also I don't understand why the list being dynamic makes a difference, everything is in the same scope and outside of any for loops - but up to you I don't know your design criteria haha.